# Wrong item deleted from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that contains an array of items in its state, but whenever I try to delete an item, the wrong one is deleted.

Here's a simplified version of my parent Component:

```
export default class BankList extends Component {
    state = {
        banks: [new Bank("Name1"), new Bank("Name2")]
    }

    addBank() {
        this.setState({banks: [...this.state.banks, new Bank("")]})
    }

    removeBank(index) {
        let good = [];
        this.state.banks.forEach((item, ind) => {
            if(ind !== index){
                good.push(item);
            }
        });
        this.setState({banks: good}); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <List>
                        {this.state.banks.map((bank, index) => <BankContainer bank={bank} key={index} id={index} onRemove={() => this.removeBank(index)}/>)}
                    </List>
                    <Content>
                        <Right>
                            <Button onPress={() => this.addBank()}>
                                <Text>Add Bank</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Content>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

The BankContainer class simply shows the Bank, and when the "remove" button inside it is pressed, it will call onChange with the provided id. I have verified that the right index is being passed into removeBank. But, after removeBank executes, the last item (index 1) is removed from the banks array, when I selected the first one (index 0). I have tried the following method bodies in removeBank, but to no avail:

Tried a shallow copy:

```
let old = [...this.state.banks];
old.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
this.setState({banks: old});
```

Tried a straight filter:

```
this.setState({banks: this.state.banks.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
```

Tried a deep copy:

```
let old = [...this.state.banks];
old = old.map(i => Object.assign({}, i));
old.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
this.setState({banks: old});
```

Tried a splice:

```
this.setState({banks: this.state.banks.splice(index, 1)});
```

Tried a shallow copy and splice:

```
let old = [...this.state.banks]
old = old.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({banks: old});
```

Tried a deep copy and splice:

```
let old = [...this.state.banks];
old = old.map(i => Object.assign({}, i));
this.setState({banks: old.splice(index, 1)})
```

None of these have worked, they have all exhibited the same behavior. I'm at my wits end on this, any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Try not to use indexes, as the indexes will shift when adding/removing items, which cause react to not rerender certain elements. Assign an actual ID to the bank, and use that as the key. Add/delete based on that key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out [Robin Pokorny’s article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

Using a stable ID, and using that to remove elements from the array, should solve your issues.